# Invalid write of size 1 while fetching data with OCILIB

Tags: c

I'm getting `Invalid write of size 1` error while running my code in valgrind:

```
==20470== Invalid write of size 1
==20470==    at 0x4E7213F: _IO_default_xsputn (in /lib64/libc-2.4.so)
==20470==    by 0x4E4A666: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.4.so)
==20470==    by 0x4E67B08: vsprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.4.so)
==20470==    by 0x4E52637: sprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.4.so)
==20470==    by 0x402875: buildQotHash (c4.c:180)
==20470==    by 0x403695: main (c4.c:469)
==20470==  Address 0xffefe1b73 is on thread 1's stack
```

I'm getting result  from database in a loop. Here snippet with marked `line 180`, which causes the error:

```
int buildQotHash(GTree* tree, char (*str)[3000])
{

    OCI_ExecuteStmt(st, query);
    rs = OCI_GetResultset(st);
    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;
    while (OCI_FetchNext(rs))
    {
      const gchar *tri = OCI_GetString (rs,  1);
      printf("%s " , tri);
      sprintf(str[j]+strlen(str[j]),"&ik%d=%s", i, tri);//<-- here is line 180
      i > 99 ? j++ : j;
      i++;
      if(i > 100) i = 1;
    }
}

int main ( void ) {
  char subStr[8][3000]={"","","","","","","",""};
  buildQotHash(t, subStr);
}
```

Comment: Where is `str` defined?

Comment: I have added missed info.

Comment: Where are you extending the storage pointed to by `str[j]` to accommodate the additional characters being added by `sprintf()`? Alternatively, if free space is accounted for at the original allocation time, do you know for sure that `strlen(str[j]) + strlen(format_string_with_variables_expanded)` does not exceed the pre-allocated storage?

Comment: It seems that you are using strlen() in an uninitialized character array. What are you expecting to return with this?

Comment: @nikpel7: This could be that. Let me check.

Comment: Shouldn't this initialize my array `char subStr[8][3000]={"","","","","","","",""};`? and give strlen 0 in the first loop?

Comment: Try adding an assert to test that `strlen(str[j])` is never more than 2900, and that `j` is never more than 7.